# How can I load model weights in Tensorflow 2.0 for multiple gpu training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load model weights in TensorFlow 2.0 for multiple GPU training. My model checkpoints are from training in Tensorflow 1.0.

This is how I used to load weights in TF1.

```
var_list = tf.trainable_variables()
for var in var_list:           
    vname = ''.join(var.name.split('semantic/'))
    val = tf.contrib.framework.load_variable(checkpoint, vname)
    tf.assign(var, val)
```

I require a similar way to load weights in tf2. I appreciate any help on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var_list = model.trainable_variables

for var in var_list:      
   vname = ''.join(var.name.split('semantic/'))
   val = tf.train.load_variable(checkpoint, vname)
   var = val
```

this is just your tf1 code in tf2, you may need to use something like

```
weights_list = model.get_weights()
for i, weight in enumerate(weights_list):
     model.layers[i] = tf.train.load_variable(checkpoint, vname)
```

depends on how you built your model